# vim set ex range to current paragraph without visual/mark etc

Tags: vim

I'm wanting to apply a command to the currect paragraph but I'd like to automate it so I don't need to visually select/mark the paragraph before-hand.

I want something like

```
:{,}s/this isn't/important/g
```

to specify the range to apply 's' (in this case) to.

Eventually I'm wanting to using range-accepting-commands to reformat a paragraph.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:'{,'}s/this isn't/important/g
```

See:

```
:h '{
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I missed. Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that '{ is usually the blank line before the current paragraph and '} is usually the blank line after. However, if the paragraph is at the top of the buffer, '{ is the first line. For things like :s///, this difference doesn't matter; for something like :sort, it certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **exclude the first and last empty lines** around the paragraph — just like the text-object "v_ip" — you can use this:

```
:'{+1,'}-1
```

For something like :sort, this will not add the last line to the top. I use this mapping to sort the current paragraph by length:

```
nn <leader>s mx:'{+1,'}-1!awk '{print length(), $0\|"sort -n"}'\|cut -d' ' -f2-<cr>`x
```

Answer (score 1):

It exists [Text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) in Vim, which `p` means paragraph.

To select a paragraph in visual mode, for example, to apply other commands to it, use `vip` or `vap`